# How to disable `tcp_slow_start_after_idle` only for selected interface or route?

Tags: linux-networking, tcp-slow-start

I'm running a server with multiple network interfaces (some are VLAN interfaces). Some of the connections are in local network with highly bursty traffic over TCP meaning they suffer at lot from having `tcp_slow_start_after_idle=1`. On the other hand, the interfaces that transmit data in real internet will probably induce more latency jitter if I don't have `tcp_slow_start_after_idle=1`.

**Is there a way to configure one interface or route to have effectively setting `tcp_slow_start_after_idle=0`, and another interface or route to have effectively the setting `tcp_slow_start_after_idle=1` at the same time?**

Having a single toggle (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_slow_start_after_idle`) for the whole system seems a bit heavy handed.

Related:

- https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/4/9/427

  - https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/4/11/83
- https://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1111.1/02240.html
- [How to apply `fq_codel` to balance traffic in multiple VLAN connections?](https://serverfault.com/q/1104394/104798)

**Update:** According to https://blog.donatas.net/blog/2015/08/08/slow-start-after-idle/ it seems that the Linux default `tcp_slow_start_after_idle=1` and `tcp_no_metrics_save=0` actually results in the worst possible throughput.